# Tkinter application topmost, even over fullscreen

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

I'm using tkinter on Ubuntu.

I'd like my application to be on top of the screen, all the time. I'm aware of, and am currently using, `wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)`. I've discovered that this is equal to right clicking on the menu bar of an application and selecting 'Always On Top', which works fine for most applications. However, this doesn't work when full-screen applications are launched (specifically, TF2). In such cases, my widget lies behind the game.

I'm also aware of `overrideredirect(True)`, and this stays on top of the game even over full-screen, but this is not viable as the menu bar and being able to move the window are central to my application.

Is there a way to have tkinter remain on top of **every** application, including those that are full-screen? Basically the functionality of `overrideredirect`, but keeping the menu bar and the ability to move the window.